# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Tags: c++

```
template <class T> class Tree
{
protected:
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //  inner class Node
    //      a single Node from a binary tree
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    template <class T> class Node
    {
    public:
        Node * left;
        Node * right;

        T value;
        Node(T val)
            : value(val), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
        Node(T val, Node<T> * l, Node<T> * r)
            : value(val), left(l), right(r){}
    };      //end of Node class

    Node<T> * root;   

public:
    Tree() {root=NULL;}  // initialize tree

};

template <class T> 
class SearchTree : public Tree<T>
{
public:
    // protocol for search trees
    void add(T value);
    bool  search(T value) {return search(root,value);   }
    void remove(T value);
    Node<T>* minimum(){return minimum(root); }
    Node<T>* findSuccessor(Node<T>* x);
    Node<T>* findParent(T val);

private:
    void add(Node<T> * current, T val);
    bool  search(Node<T>* current, T val);
    Node<T>* minimum(Node<T>* current);

};

// THE ERROR IS HERE
template <class T>
Node<T>* searchTree<T>::minimum(Node<T>* current);
{
    while (current->left != NULL)
        curent= current->left;
    return current;
}
```

** i want to do a function that will return a pointer of Node,
 i think because the template it causing me an error,
 do i have another way to implement the function?**

Comment: You should mark BЈовић's or Blazes' answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo here:

```
Node<T>* searchTree<T>::minimum(Node<T>* current);
```

`searchTree` should be `SearchTree` with a capital `S`.

Comment: @VJo: No, I just looked at the error line and saw the typo. Compiling should be the OP's job IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Wow it was a challenge to fix your example.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> class Tree
{
    protected:
        //--------------------------------------------------------
        //  inner class Node
        //      a single Node from a binary tree
        //--------------------------------------------------------

        template <class T1> class Node
        {
            public:
                Node * left;
                Node * right;

                T1 value;
                Node(T1 val) : value(val), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
                Node(T1 val, Node<T1> * l, Node<T1> * r) : value(val), left(l), right(r){}
        };      //end of Node class

        Node<T> * root;

    public:
        Tree() {root=NULL;}  // initialize tree

};

template < class T >
class SearchTree : public Tree< T >
{
    public:
        // protocol for search trees
        void add(T value);
        bool  search(T value) {return search(Tree< T >::root,value);   }
        void remove(T value);
        typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >* minimum(){return minimum(Tree< T >::root); }
        typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >* findSuccessor(typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >* x);
        typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >* findParent(T val);

    private:
        void add(typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >* current, T val);
        bool  search(typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >* current, T val);
        typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >* minimum(typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >* current);

};

// THE ERROR IS HERE
template <class T>
typename Tree< T >::template Node< T >*
    SearchTree< T >::minimum( typename Tree< T >::template Node< T > * current )
{
    while (current->left != NULL)
        current= current->left;
    return current;
}

int main()
{
    SearchTree< int > obj;
}
```

I think you got into more complex thing then you thought, and the line you marked is not the only problem.

Lookup dependant names and templates.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong... your Node does not need to be a template as it is already; you had a typo with `searchTree<T>::minimum` (capitalize)... Node is part of Tree, so it requires scope.

```
template <class T> class Tree
{
protected:
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //  inner class Node
    //      a single Node from a binary tree
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node * left;
        Node * right;

        T value;
        Node(T val)
            : value(val), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
        Node(T val, Node * l, Node * r)
            : value(val), left(l), right(r){}
    };      //end of Node class

    Node * root;   

public:
    Tree() {root=NULL;}  // initialize tree

};

template <class T> 
class SearchTree : public Tree<T>
{
public:
    // protocol for search trees
    void add(T value);
    bool  search(T value) {return search(root,value);   }
    void remove(T value);
    Node* minimum(){return minimum(root); }
    Node* findSuccessor(Node* x);
    Node* findParent(T val);

private:
    void add(Node * current, T val);
    bool  search(Node* current, T val);
    Node* minimum(Node* current);
};

template <class T>
SearchTree<T>::Tree::Node* SearchTree<T>::minimum(SearchTree<T>::Tree::Node* current)
{
    while (current->left != NULL)
        curent= current->left;
    return current;
}
```